# Spacewalk 1.7 - system overview - 0 packages?

Tags: centos, spacewalk

I have some systems, that are long now with Centos 6 channel associated.

In the systems overview of the SpaceWalk server 1.7 I see only that all of the Centos 6 systems are ok , and 0 Packages to be installed, except at one server that has an issue, that he has some broken packages.

The channel it self syncs ok, but does not check the clients.

Thanks in advance